# How to set AWS API gateway integration request to lambda function correctly using Ansible?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-lambda, swagger

I'm trying to create a straightforward Python lambda function connected to API gateway using Ansible. I've got everything setup to work correctly, except the API gateway always adds a colon and an integer to the lambda function arn. When calling the API, I get internal server error. If I simply remove this additional integer (the version number I believe) on the web console and redeploy I get the expected response when calling the API. However, I'd really like to have this fully automatic with Ansible, but can't see how to correctly choose the lambda function version when setting up the API gateway. How do I set the lambda function name for the API gateway in Ansible, without it appending a version number?

Ansible code:

```
- name: Create API gateway
  aws_api_gateway:
    state: present
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key_id }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_access_key }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    swagger_file: roles/aws-api-proxy/templates/swagger_complete.j2
    stage: production
    deploy_desc: Production Deployment
  register: apigateway_result
```

My swagger file:

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "2017-10-27T10:39:47Z"
  title: "apiproxyfunction"

basePath: "/prod"
schemes:
- "https"
paths:
  /submit:
    post:
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
                 uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/{{ lambda_result.configuration.function_arn }}/invocations"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        contentHandling: "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
        type: "aws_proxy"
definitions:
  Empty:
    type: "object"
    title: "Empty Schema"
```

The {{ lambda_result.configuration.function_arn }} variable is taken from when I create the lambda function which is like this:

```
arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:MYACCOUNTID:function:apiproxyfunctionXYZ
```

However, in the web console, the API gateway resource section; lambda integration request Lambda Function ends up being- apiproxyfunctionXYZ:1

So how to remove the :1? Or is there another workaround?

Please ask if you need more background details.

EDIT - see screenshot of console FYI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Set lambda_arn fact
  set_fact:
    lambda_arn: "{{ lambda_data.configuration.function_arn.split(':')[0:7] | join(':') }}"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.